# I want to resize post featured image without cropping image. How?

Tags: theme-development, images, post-thumbnails

I want show post featured image on different page in different size but image in not showing full. Also, do not want to crop image.
I am adding an link that what type of work I want do. [Example](https://lacomparaison.fr/thermos/) When you check shared link post then you see that post thumbnail image is showing full on post page, category page, home page in different size. Please guide me how to achieve this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.